# doGet not work in servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have servlet of registration.

```
@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
System.out.println("in servlet");
}
}
```

If I go to that page I get

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
```

If I change @WebServlet("/register") in @WebServlet("/register1") all works correctly.
How do I fix this situation?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>booker</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>controllers</param-name>
        <param-value>com.epam.task.controller</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>



</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you add your web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the web.xml and change the servlet name and url to register. Or kindly upload the web.xml too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check from action in your jsp ,it might be incorrect.

Comment: I dont forward to jsp. Only do action on servlet.

Comment: ok ...please post from where you want to call this servlet .

Comment: http://localhost:8080/booker/register its addres where I call this servlet.
and when I change @WebServlet("/register1") and call http://localhost:8080/booker/register1 all works.